# How to identify values before and after a sequence of NAs

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a data set of CO2 measurements taken from an instrument in the lab. Standards were also run sporadically throughout the data collection process. A mock dataset would look like this:

```
tibble(co2=c(464,345,389,831,374,323,486,542,429,624,359,612,738,720,520,454,499,616,952,805,582, 646,566,781,745,615,639,750,780,1119,584,1345,1020,1038,1419,1136),
number.stds=c(3,rep('NA',13),2,rep('NA',20),3),
std.value.1=c(618,rep('NA',13),534,rep('NA',20),546),
std.value.2=c(621,rep('NA',13),564,rep('NA',20),549),
std.value.3=c(625,rep('NA',34),553)) -> data
```

Column `co2` are the measured data, `number.stds` is the number of standard measurements taken, and `std.value.1` through `std.value.3` are the different standard readings.

I want to generate a new column `std.value` that is the average of all standard values of adjacent standard runs, and assigned to all the samples measured in between these two standard runs.

For the example, this new column would have the value of 592.4 (`mean(c(618,621,625,534,564))`) for rows 1 through 15, inclusive. And it would have the value of 549.2 (`mean(c(546,549,553,534,564))`) for all rows from 16 to 36, inclusive.

Is there a simple way to do this with dplyr? Should the data be collected and organized in a different format to make this problem easier?

Comment: 534 and 564 is not showed

Comment: Your examples were created `NA` as "NA", changing the columns from numeric to character/factor

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting problem. I would welcome anyone who has a better answer. This is technically done in `dplyr` but is basically a base R workflow that is forced into a tidyverse statement without really using tidyverse code. I think it is a general solution but I arrived at it with trial and error.

First create the example `data` with true `NA` values rather than character string `"NA"`. Then find the row indices for the first and second standard run that corresponds with each row of the data. This is done with a statement that correctly handles the edge cases for rows 1, 15, and 36. Finally, go through each row of `data` and average all the values for both standard runs together to yield a single mean -- this requires converting it to a vector and removing `NA` values.

### code to create input data

```
tibble(co2=c(464,345,389,831,374,323,486,542,429,624,359,612,738,720,520,454,499,616,952,805,582, 646,566,781,745,615,639,750,780,1119,584,1345,1020,1038,1419,1136),
       number.stds=c(3,rep(NA,13),2,rep(NA,20),3),
       std.value.1=c(618,rep(NA,13),534,rep(NA,20),546),
       std.value.2=c(621,rep(NA,13),564,rep(NA,20),549),
       std.value.3=c(625,rep(NA,34),553)) -> data
```

### code to process data

```
std_rows = which(!is.na(data$number.stds))
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(index1 = sapply(1:nrow(data), 
                         function(i) max(c(1,std_rows[which(i > std_rows)]))),
         index2 = sapply(1:nrow(data), 
                         function(i) min(std_rows[-1][which(i <= std_rows[-1])])))

data %>%
  mutate(standard_mean = 
           apply(data, 1, function(x) mean(unlist(data[x[c("index1", "index2")], grep('std.value', names(data))]), na.rm = TRUE)))
```

### output

```
# A tibble: 36 x 8
     co2 number.stds std.value.1 std.value.2 std.value.3 index1 index2 standard_mean
   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>  <int>         <dbl>
 1   464           3         618         621         625      1     15          592.
 2   345          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 3   389          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 4   831          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 5   374          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 6   323          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 7   486          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 8   542          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
 9   429          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
10   624          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
11   359          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
12   612          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
13   738          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
14   720          NA          NA          NA          NA      1     15          592.
15   520           2         534         564          NA      1     15          592.
16   454          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
17   499          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
18   616          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
19   952          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
20   805          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
21   582          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
22   646          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
23   566          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
24   781          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
25   745          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
26   615          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
27   639          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
28   750          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
29   780          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
30  1119          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
31   584          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
32  1345          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
33  1020          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
34  1038          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
35  1419          NA          NA          NA          NA     15     36          549.
36  1136           3         546         549         553     15     36          549.
```

As requested, rows 1-15 include the mean of all five values from rows 1 and 15 combined, and rows 16-26 include the mean of all five values from rows 15 and 36 combined.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I misunderstood the request, initially. Here is an answer that should get you what you're looking for.

@qdread's answer is nice and concise. This one is lengthier but sticks to tidyverse syntax.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- data %>% mutate(grp.start = if_else(!is.na(number.stds), 1, 0),
                        smpl.grp = cumsum(grp.start),
                        smpl.grp = if_else(!is.na(number.stds) & row_number() != 1, lag(smpl.grp), smpl.grp)) %>% 
  select(smpl.grp, everything(), -grp.start)


data.2 <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(number.stds)) %>%
  select(smpl.grp, std.value.1:std.value.3) %>% 
  mutate(smpl.grp = if_else(row_number() == 1, 0, smpl.grp)) %>% #assigns first row a grp # of 0 but keeps its standard values in our dataset, takes care of edge issues going forward.
  pivot_longer(std.value.1:std.value.3, names_to = "standard.rep", names_prefix = "std.value.", values_to = "std.values") %>% 
  select(standard.rep, everything()) %>%
  group_by(standard.rep) %>% 
  arrange(standard.rep, smpl.grp) %>% 
  mutate(std.values.2 = lag(std.values)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(std.values:std.values.2, names_to = "std.grps", values_to = "std.values") %>% 
  group_by(smpl.grp) %>% 
  summarise(std.n = sum(!is.na(std.values)), std.avg = mean(std.values, na.rm = T)) %>% 
  left_join(select(data, smpl.grp, co2), .)

data.2
```

```
# A tibble: 36 x 4
   smpl.grp   co2 std.n std.avg
      <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl>
 1        1   464     5    592.
 2        1   345     5    592.
 3        1   389     5    592.
 4        1   831     5    592.
 5        1   374     5    592.
 6        1   323     5    592.
 7        1   486     5    592.
 8        1   542     5    592.
 9        1   429     5    592.
10        1   624     5    592.
# … with 26 more rows
```

First, I assigned a unique identifier to each group of samples ("smpl.grp") you'd like to compare to different sets of standard averages

Then, we can remove extraneous rows and work with only the relevant data: sample group numbers & standard values.

The next step tidies the data somewhat with `pivot_longer()` so that all standard values are in a single column.

Data is then grouped by standard rep, and arranged by standard rep and sample group ID. This sets things up to generate an additional column with the second set of standard values you'd like to associate with that group using `mutate()` and `lag()`.

By pivoting again, you again ensure all your standard values are in one column, and now all are associated with their desired sample group ids.

Then all that's left to do is `summarise()` by sample group and join with the original data set by smpl.grp.

**DATA** (with true `NA`s)

```
tibble(co2=c(464,345,389,831,374,323,486,542,429,624,359,612,738,720,520,454,499,616,952,805,582, 646,566,781,745,615,639,750,780,1119,584,1345,1020,1038,1419,1136),
       number.stds=c(3,rep(NA_real_,13),2,rep(NA_real_,20),3),
       std.value.1=c(618,rep(NA_real_,13),534,rep(NA_real_,20),546),
       std.value.2=c(621,rep(NA_real_,13),564,rep(NA_real_,20),549),
       std.value.3=c(625,rep(NA_real_,34),553)) -> data
```

Comment: Per @akrun's comments: You discuss finding means of 5 values in your question, but only provide 3 'std.value' columns in your sample data. The data in my answer are the same that you provided, but 'NA' was changed to 'NA_real_'

Comment: I don't think this is correct based on what OP wanted. He requested the two closest standard runs to each row be averaged, not a single run.

Comment: @qdread, You're right! I definitely misunderstood. I updated my answer to provide a more tidyverse-centric approach.